# Identifying individual session in between household session in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a code where I have got two independent data sets i.e. Household viewing data. if a whole household starts watching something between 2PM to 3PM (mentioned in seconds format). there are five individuals of the same household watched that session but for different duration. i.e.

```
DATASET1 - HOUSEHOLD DATA

household start_time end_time channel duration_watched
one       50400      54000     A      3600   

DATASET2 - INDIVIDUAL DATA

household   individual   start_time end_time channel duration_watched
one             1          50400      51300     A      900   
one             2          50800      52400     A      1600   
one             3          52400      52900     A      900   
one             4          51000      54000     A      3000   

EXPECTED OUTPUT iS identifying the individual sessions of the household session

DATASET OUTPUT


household   individual   start_time end_time channel duration_watched   IDENTIFICATION
one             1          50400      51300     A      900                HH SESSION
one             2          50800      52400     A      1600               HH SESSION
one             3          52400      52900     A      900                HH SESSION
one             4          51000      54000     A      3000               HH SESSION
```

I tried with for, it didn't work.

- I have got many household sessions and individual sessions that has to be identified pertaining to these household sessions.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Srikanth from where it comes columns identification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using a condition on `household` and on `channel` to join your data.

## Data

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt1 = """household start_time end_time channel duration_watched
one       50400      54000     A      3600"""

txt2 = """household   individual   start_time end_time channel duration_watched
one             1          50400      51300     A      900   
one             2          50800      52400     A      1600   
one             3          52400      52900     A      900   
one             4          51000      54000     A      3000"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt1), delim_whitespace=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt2), delim_whitespace=True)
```

Now I'm going to merge (or join if you prefer). It seems to me that you don't need `"duration_watched"` from `df1` then we need to change `"start_time"` and `"end_time"` columns names.

```py
df1 = df1.drop(["duration_watched"], axis=1)\
         .rename(columns={"start_time":"start",
                          "end_time":"end"})
```

Here I'm assuming you are joining on `"household", "channel"` (if this is not the case then drop `"channel"` from df1)

```py
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="left", on=["household", "channel"])
```

Finally there is your filter and you can get rid of `["start", "end"]` columns.

```py
df = df[df["start_time"].between(df["start"], df["end"]) &
        df["end_time"].between(df["start"], df["end"])]

df = df.drop(["start", "end"], axis=1)
```

and `print(df)` should return

```
  household channel  individual  start_time  end_time  duration_watched
0       one       A           1       50400     51300               900
1       one       A           2       50800     52400              1600
2       one       A           3       52400     52900               900
3       one       A           4       51000     54000              3000
```

Now in case your dataframe are huge and don't fit in memory you might consider using [dask](https://dask.org/) or [vaex](https://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).